# How can I create this in blender?

Tags: 3d-view

I am extremely new to Blender and I need help creating this in blender.

[image]

Comment: If you want to do that in Blender, you need to model it and then texture it and voila.

Comment: This is topic for a book or long tutorial series, if everything should be explained from beginning. Just go to YT and search for modeling tutorials. When you are ableto  create models you need, just search for hand painted textures in Blender.  Come back with specific well-defined question, not with question in style:  "I know nothing and I want to know everything". This kind of questions can't be answered. 3D is about neverending learning

Comment: @Shubol3D Just guide me and I will do the hard work geez -_-

Comment: @Mzidare Any tips on how to model it? thank you <3

Comment: just search: "blender beginner modeling tutorials" there are dozens stuff like this all over internet. Thils serie was created by one most knows Blender tutorial creator, can be good for start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYj6e-72RDs

Comment: Wow, a score of -10... that is impressive. It would probably have been voted positively if you had asked how to model or texture a specific part, instead of the whole scene...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Shubol3D Said, 3D is a never ending learning experience. So basically what ever you do now, you will be able to perfect later as you learn more and more about the topic. For this i would just start of by picturing the image as a 3D image/Model in your Mind. Start at the bottom by adding cubes. Don't detail the model yet as you need to get the basic shape first. Because 3D Art takes time, if your rush it, it will turn out horribly so take your time. After you have the basic shape then you can start detailing by adding vertices and edges and subdividing the cubes. And then to take it a step further you can sculpt it into the shapes like the image has. Once you are happy you add your Textures, set up your lighting and then Render. However, it is highly likely your Render will look nothing like this because when you are modelling it you should have ideas come to life in your mind and you slowly start to create your own version of it.
But anyway hope that gave you a little bit of an insight to what you want to achieve.
Good luck

Comment: First of all, thank you for being polite :D..Secondly, should I use a cube or cone?

Comment: Use a cube Mate, I know the image is a shape of a cone but it is built up of cubes. Also cubes give you more freedom when detailing as you can texture it easier and also allows you to sculpt it easier. And for this Render you are probably aiming for for something that is quick to render. So cubes are the best choice because they have 6 faces. So yea use a cube. If this Answered your Question then please click the tick button next to my answer to say to others it has been answered. Also are you using blender render or Cycles Render?

Comment: If you dont understand why cubes think of this image as a lego thing, Each brick is a cube so just build it up. When you get better and feel comfortable using cubes try changing to Plane's as they only use 2 faces.  But for this and for you now use cubes.

Comment: I'm using blender render...OK i will use cubes and see how it goes

Comment: If you get a chance change it to cycles, i mean if you want to as shadowing and lighting are 10 times better and the overall result looks awesome. But anyway Good Luck with your render and i hope you enjoy your creations. And if you ever need advice just go to my profile, Jump to my website and send me an email down the bottom with what you need and i will try to walk you in depth and maybe even show you images demonstrating how. GL

Comment: Do I need only one cube or multiple?

Comment: See on the scene how they appear like bricks, Have multiple cubes and sculpt them to the image you see, so for this image there are roughly 29 Bricks, so make this scene with 29 Bricks and then model the top. Again think of them as Lego. Picture modeling this scene as Lego bricks. thats how I could best describe this for you.

Comment: OK now how can I color it?

Comment: @SarshaW congratulations. You just got yourself your own padawan :)

Comment: Are you texturing or do you want a solid diffuse colour.